# CSS :not performance

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is the browser able to optimize longer `:not` chains or would that cause negative performance impacts?

Simplified example:

```
.animal:not(.cow):not(.dog):not(.cat):not(.bird):not(.unicorn):not(.tiger) {
   display: none !important
}
```

The idea behind is that I want to hide those animals but

1. I don't know how those animals are styled. E.g. `cow` might have `display:table`, `tiger` might have `display:flex` and `.unicorn` might even have `display: none`
2. I don't know about the specificity of the animals original selectors

Comment: Follow the golden rule of optimization: optimize when you see you have a performance problem, and only then. You have to work very hard to cause CSS performance problems, and a few `:not()`s is unlikely to cause a problem. What is more worrisome is that your code does not look very scalable; you'll have to change it every time you have a new type of animal you don't want to display.

Comment: Compared to `* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }` you should be safe :p About 2, if you've an educated guess about the maximum specificity, a trick is to multiply the number of classes... with the same class like `.animal.animal.animal` = (0,0,3,0). But adding `!important` to `display: none` seems OK to me due to constraints, it isn't as annoying in the future as a margin or color

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the books and other writings I read about CSS, it does not seem a problem. This is an excellent book (Scalable and Modular Architecture for CSS - Jonathan Snook) extract about [Selector Performance](http://smacss.com/book/selectors).

Comment: [@itacode](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3943888/itacode) the link seems to be broken, can you update it or at least give the title and author’s name?

Comment: UPD: it’s [here](http://smacss.com/book/selectors), they use http instead of https